# How would I calculate the distances between multiple cells in R?

Tags: r

I have multiple different phenotypes and xy coordinates for each cell. What would be the easiest way to calculate distances between each of my cells within the same slide? My dataset has 100,000+  cells so I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to do this.

An example dataframe would be:

```r
Xposition <- c(1,6,4,7,9,4,8,6,4)

Yposition <- c(6,3,2,6,3,6,1,3,7)

Phenotype <- c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B")

SlideID <- c(111,111,111,111,111,112,112,112,112)

df <- data.frame(Xposition, Yposition, Phenotype, SlideID)
```

I'm looking for something that could give me a dataframe where the outputs are something like:

```r
CellType1 <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B")

Celltype2 <- c("A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")

Distance <- c("5.83", "5", "6", "8.54", "2.23", "3.16", "3", "5", "5.09", "3.6", "6.4", "3.6", "1", "2.82", "7.21", "4.47")

SlideID <- c("111", "111", "111", "111", "111", "111", "111", "111", "111", "111", "112", "112", "112", "112", "112", "112")

distancedf <- data.frame(CellType1, Celltype2, Distance, SlideID)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Everything in the second frame is `character`, even though I'm inferring that you need `numeric` for `Distance`, and `SlideID` is originally `numeric` as well. Is that meaningful?

Comment: `testXposition` not found ... do you mean `Xposition`?

Comment: @r2evans yes, thanks for pointing that out! I changed it

Answer (score 0):

I think there is room for ambiguity here, but ...

```r
res <- as.data.frame.table(as.matrix(dist(df[,1:2])))
res$Var2 <- df$Phenotype[res$Var2]
res$SlideID <- df$SlideID[res$Var1]
res$Var1 <- df$Phenotype[res$Var1]
head(res)
#   Var1 Var2     Freq SlideID
# 1    A    A 0.000000     111
# 2    A    A 5.830952     111
# 3    B    A 5.000000     111
# 4    C    A 6.000000     111
# 5    C    A 8.544004     111
# 6    A    A 3.000000     112
```

From this, you should be able to filter out the `0`s fairly easily, but I wanted to keep it here to show what is actually happening. Effectively, that `as.data.frame.table(...)` is going from this

```r
dist(df[,1:2])
#          1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8
# 2 5.830952                                                               
# 3 5.000000 2.236068                                                      
# 4 6.000000 3.162278 5.000000                                             
# 5 8.544004 3.000000 5.099020 3.605551                                    
# 6 3.000000 3.605551 4.000000 3.000000 5.830952                           
# 7 8.602325 2.828427 4.123106 5.099020 2.236068 6.403124                  
# 8 5.830952 0.000000 2.236068 3.162278 3.000000 3.605551 2.828427         
# 9 3.162278 4.472136 5.000000 3.162278 6.403124 1.000000 7.211103 4.472136
```

*through* this:

```r
as.matrix(dist(df[,1:2]))
#          1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9
# 1 0.000000 5.830952 5.000000 6.000000 8.544004 3.000000 8.602325 5.830952 3.162278
# 2 5.830952 0.000000 2.236068 3.162278 3.000000 3.605551 2.828427 0.000000 4.472136
# 3 5.000000 2.236068 0.000000 5.000000 5.099020 4.000000 4.123106 2.236068 5.000000
# 4 6.000000 3.162278 5.000000 0.000000 3.605551 3.000000 5.099020 3.162278 3.162278
# 5 8.544004 3.000000 5.099020 3.605551 0.000000 5.830952 2.236068 3.000000 6.403124
# 6 3.000000 3.605551 4.000000 3.000000 5.830952 0.000000 6.403124 3.605551 1.000000
# 7 8.602325 2.828427 4.123106 5.099020 2.236068 6.403124 0.000000 2.828427 7.211103
# 8 5.830952 0.000000 2.236068 3.162278 3.000000 3.605551 2.828427 0.000000 4.472136
# 9 3.162278 4.472136 5.000000 3.162278 6.403124 1.000000 7.211103 4.472136 0.000000
```

ultimately to this

```r
head(as.data.frame.table(as.matrix(dist(df[,1:2]))))
#   Var1 Var2     Freq
# 1    1    1 0.000000
# 2    2    1 5.830952
# 3    3    1 5.000000
# 4    4    1 6.000000
# 5    5    1 8.544004
# 6    6    1 3.000000
```

and the `0.000`s are the diagonals of the distance matrix (that are masked in the default representation of `dist(...)`).

---

Per `SlideID`:

```r
lapply(split(df, df$SlideID), function(x) { 
  res <- as.data.frame.table(as.matrix(dist(x[,1:2])))
  res$Var2 <- x$Phenotype[res$Var2]
  res$SlideID <- x$SlideID[res$Var1]
  res$Var1 <- x$Phenotype[res$Var1]
  res
})
# $`111`
#    Var1 Var2     Freq SlideID
# 1     A    A 0.000000     111
# 2     A    A 5.830952     111
# 3     B    A 5.000000     111
# 4     C    A 6.000000     111
# 5     C    A 8.544004     111
# 6     A    A 5.830952     111
# 7     A    A 0.000000     111
# 8     B    A 2.236068     111
# 9     C    A 3.162278     111
# 10    C    A 3.000000     111
# 11    A    B 5.000000     111
# 12    A    B 2.236068     111
# 13    B    B 0.000000     111
# 14    C    B 5.000000     111
# 15    C    B 5.099020     111
# 16    A    C 6.000000     111
# 17    A    C 3.162278     111
# 18    B    C 5.000000     111
# 19    C    C 0.000000     111
# 20    C    C 3.605551     111
# 21    A    C 8.544004     111
# 22    A    C 3.000000     111
# 23    B    C 5.099020     111
# 24    C    C 3.605551     111
# 25    C    C 0.000000     111
# $`112`
#    Var1 Var2     Freq SlideID
# 1     A    A 0.000000     112
# 2     A    A 6.403124     112
# 3     B    A 3.605551     112
# 4     B    A 1.000000     112
# 5     A    A 6.403124     112
# 6     A    A 0.000000     112
# 7     B    A 2.828427     112
# 8     B    A 7.211103     112
# 9     A    B 3.605551     112
# 10    A    B 2.828427     112
# 11    B    B 0.000000     112
# 12    B    B 4.472136     112
# 13    A    B 1.000000     112
# 14    A    B 7.211103     112
# 15    B    B 4.472136     112
# 16    B    B 0.000000     112
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! When the distance calculations are made, does this keep calculations only between cells from the same slide ID? Or should I use a loop to subset the data for each slide?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you look at the output in the last code block (Var1 from 1 to 6, Var 2 steady at 1), shows that the first six rows are all compared with just the first row. If you don't do `head`, you'll see the rest, that it is a cartesian expansion, comparing each row with each row. This means that you will have the self-v-self distances (all 0, the diagonal of the matrix in the previous code block), which can be easily filtered out.

Comment: So when I use your code without subsetting the data, I get 81 observations. When I subset so that only Slide 111 is used, I get 25 observations. When I subset for only Slide 112, I get 16 variables. The res data frame should have 41 observations. I subset the data because I only want to calculate distances for cells from the same slide. What it looks like to me is that without subsetting the data, distance calculations are being made between cells from different slide IDs, producing >41 observations in the res dataframe

Comment: I see, your *"within the same slide"* comment now makes sense. Well, use this process, but on each subframe using `split(df, df$SlideID)`.

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to tell me what the difference is between doing it with lapply and by doing it with this other solution that I thought of? `distances = list()
for (i in 1:length(SlideIDlist)){
  distances[[SlideIDlist[i]]] <- as.data.frame.table(as.matrix(dist(df[df$SlideID== SlideIDlist[i],][,1:2])))
  
  distances[[ROIlist[i]]]$Var2 <- df$Phenotype[distances[[SlideIDlist[i]]]$Var2]
  distances[[ROIlist[i]]]$ROIID <- df$SlideID[distances[[SlideIDlist[i]]]$Var1]
  distances[[ROIlist[i]]]$Var1 <- df$Phenotype[distances[[SlideIDlist[i]]]$Var1]
  }`

Comment: I'm inferring `SlideIDlist <- unique(df$SlideID)` and `ROIlist` should really be `SlideIDlist`. Your indexing is broken: because `SlideID` is numeric, then the first time is tries to do `distances[[111]]`, which pre-fills the list with 110 empty lists (blanks). You can either do `distances[[i]]` or `distances[[as.character(SlideIDlist[i])]]` (use that same index variable in all places, total seven?). Other than that, values are the same. (Oh, and your `for` loop takes over 12x as long.)

Comment: I did mistakenly paste ROIlist instead of SlideIDlist; I copied/pasted from my code and missed changing that when posting it here. I'll use lapply. Thanks for explaining everything!